# Validating SSL clients using a list of authorised certificates instead of a Certificate Authority

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, mod-ssl

Is it possible to configure Apache (or any other SSL-aware server) to only accept connections from clients presenting a certificate from a pre-defined list? These certificates may be signed by any CA (and may be self-signed).

A while back I tried to get client certificate validation working in the EPP system of the domain registry I work for. The [EPP protocol spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5734.txt) mandates use of "mutual strong client-server authentication". In practice, this means that both the client *and* the server must validate the certificate of the other peer in the session.

We created a private certificate authority and asked registrars to submit CSRs, which we then signed. This seemed to us to be the simplest solution, but many of our registrars objected: they were used to obtaining a client certificate from a CA, and submitting that certificate to the registry. So we had to scrap the system. I have been trying to find a way of implementing this system in our server, which is based on the [mod_epp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aepps) module for Apache.

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible to do with just the core mod_ssl, using SSLRequire. Im not sure the exact SSL variable you would want, but something like this should work:

SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_UID} in { file("/tmp/list") }

Alternatively, you can map some certificate attribute to the user name that usually comes from HTTP Authentication (.htaccess type restrictions):

.htaccess:

SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth
SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN
AuthGroupFile /tmp/SSL_Groups
Require group my-users

/tmp/SSL_Groups:

my-users: uid=bob,dc=site,dc=com uid=jane,dc=site,dc=com

Again, I'm not 100% on what SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN looks like, but you get the point.

Comment: I have a further question about the SSLRequire directive: I am having trouble getting the file() function to work. Doing this works fine with a test certificate:

SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL} in { "[hex code]" }

as does this, but only if /tmp/list contains only a single serial number, without a terminating newline:

SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN} in { file("/tmp/list") }

What format should the file be in? I've tried separating entries with newlines and commas with no joy.

Comment: Further to my earlier comment: the file() function is extremely limited, and won't work in the way you've described: it is interpreted purely as a string, so you can't put multiple DNs in a file and have Apache grep the file.

Comment: Well, I think the +FakeBasicAuth should work as described.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to setup a directory with all the CA certificates you trust and then point at that with the [SSLCACertificatePath](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcacertificatepath) directive so you can authenticated based on any certificate.  Then as Jeff mentioned use [SSLRequire](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire) to limit access to the set of certificates you want to permit.

If your system doesn't already have a set of common CAs certs installed then you could copy them from somewhere else.  The Debian the [ca-certificates](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/all/ca-certificates/filelist) package may be a good starting point.

Comment: interesting but it sounds like the client would still needs to accept the 3rd party certs and install them into their own cert store right?

Comment: @djangofan, Yes, to authenticate with a client certificate the end-user must get the certificate from somewhere and install it into the certificate store used by their browser.